# create contents of new window from data generated in electron's main process

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I am trying to pass data from the main window of an electron application to a
new window, which is opened as a result of a user action, but I can't seem to get the
interprocess communication working.
The following is a minimal example illustrating my problem.
For the sake of conciseness, I have included all javascript-code which is part of the
rendering process into the html-pages.

body of index.html:

```
<body>
    <h1>Passing data to new window</h1>
    <input id="testBtn" type="button" value="Testclick"></input>

    <script>
        const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
        testBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
           ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', '')
           console.log("sent asynchronously")
         });
    </script>
</body>
```

The relevant part of the main process index.js:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
    window = new BrowserWindow({
      webPreferences: {
         nodeIntegration: true
         },
      width: 800, height: 600
     })
    window.loadFile('index.html')
    window.openDevTools();
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

const { readFileSync } = require('fs')

//sample data: read project package-file
function readConfig () {
  const data = readFileSync('./package.json', 'utf8')
  return data
}
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log("asynchronous-message triggered")
  console.log(arg)
  subwindow = new BrowserWindow({
      webPreferences: {
         nodeIntegration: true
         },
      width: 800, height: 600
     })
  console.log("after creating subwindow...")
  subwindow.loadFile('sub.html')
  subwindow.webContents.send('filecontents-msg', readConfig());
  subwindow.openDevTools();
})
```

relevant part of sub.html:

```
 <body>
    <h1>SUBWINDOW</h1>
    <p id="fileContents"></p>
  <script>
      console.log("executing script of sub.html")
      const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
      ipcRenderer.on('filecontents-msg', (event, arg) => {
          console.log("processing message filecontents-msg")
          document.getElementById("fileContents").innerHTML = arg;
      })
  </script>
  </body>
```

The script in sub.html is executed, but apparently 'filecontents-msg' is never received (i.e.
the function body of the function passed to `ipcRenderer.on` is never executed,
neither when I replace the line

```
subwindow.webContents.send('filecontents-msg', readConfig());
```

in index.js by

```
event.reply('filecontents-msg', readConfig())
```

Could someone please give a working example of how to pass data from the main-process to a new window,
triggered by some user event in another window?

Comment: what if you just `await` the `loadFile` call before sending the message?

Comment: @pushkin Many thanks for this hint, I suppose this also solves the problem of the message being sent before the new window is ready (like in the workaround I have posted as an answer). When I just add ```await``` before the ```loadFile``` command I get an Exception though - could you maybe provide an answer showing how it works (and optimally explain why the above does not)?

Comment: what exception do you get

Comment: Looking at it again, it was actually an ```Uncaught Exception``` due to a ```SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function```

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the problem has to do with the message being sent before the new window is ready. I found that the data is loaded correctly into the new window when I modify
the load and send commands in index.js like this:

```
  subwindow.loadFile('sub.html');
  subwindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    subwindow.webContents.send('filecontents-msg', readConfig())
  })
```